# time complexity - bigO notation

Tags: big-o

```
def my_sum(i, j):
    if i == j:
        return i
    mid = (i + j) //2
    return my_sum(i, mid) + my_sum(mid + 1, j)
```

Why is it `O(j - i)` and not `O(log n)`? `(j >= i)`

Comment: Not sure. Did you try to run that algorithm and observe the steps it is doing? That often helps to *really* grasp what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm splits `j-i` in half for each recursive call. The recursion depth will be number of recursive calls needed to get `i == j` which will be `log2(j-i)` for every branch.

So the algorithm forms a recursion tree with a branching factor, `b`, of `2`, and a depth, `d`, of `log2(j-i)`. The time complexity is the number of items in the tree:

```
  b^d
= 2^log2(j-i)
= j-i
```